# How do Allow only Admins to have access to the Admin page in Nodejs `AdminBro`

Tags: node.js, express, admin-bro

How do Allow only Admins to have access to the Admin page in `AdminBro`? `Nodejs`

All that I want is for only Admins to have access to the `adminBro` page, is there any specific method to get this done?

I did this in my `app.js` file but it's not working

```
app.get("/admin", function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.login = req.user;
  if (res.locals.login.roles == "admin") {
     app.use("/admin", adminRouter);
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use new `app.use` inside `app.get`, as `(req, res, next)` are already consumed. You have two of choice:

1. Your route in if condition body

```
if (res.locals.login.roles === 'admin') {
   // your admin route logic
   res.send('admin page')
} else {
  res.redirect('/')
}
```

2. I'm used to use small middleware function like this one:

```
const isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user.roles === 'admin') {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Then you use it in whichever route this way:

```
app.get('/admin', isAdmin, adminRouter)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the middleware solution is what I have been looking for, I did as you suggested and it's working very well. @Fide